# MATLAB H5 files cannot exceed 2GB

Tags: matlab, hdf5

If I create a h5 file larger than 2GB, I get an error. Smaller than 2GB things work fine. I didn't think this filesize was a problem with the h5 format. This seems to not be a problem on my windows 8.1 machine, but is on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

### MWE:

```
fname = 'tmp001.h5';
h5create(fname,'/DS1',[195 2048 1500],'DataType','single'); % doesn't work
h5write(fname,'/DS1',1,[1 1 1],[1 1 1]);

fname = 'tmp002.h5';
h5create(fname,'/DS1',[195 2048 1400],'DataType','single');% doesn't work
h5write(fname,'/DS1',1,[1 1 1],[1 1 1]);

fname = 'tmp003.h5';
h5create(fname,'/DS1',[195 2048 1300],'DataType','single');% does work
h5write(fname,'/DS1',1,[1 1 1],[1 1 1]);
```

This only seems to be a problem if I give it only a segment of the data set, and even then it works providing the size of the data is more than 2^14! See files 4 and 5:

```
fname = 'tmp004.h5';
h5create(fname,'/DS1',[536886273],'DataType','single');% does work
h5write(fname,'/DS1',rand(536886273,1)); % filesize > 2gb but length > 2^14

fname = 'tmp005.h5';
h5create(fname,'/DS1',[536886273],'DataType','single');% doesn't work
h5write(fname,'/DS1',1,1,1); % filesize > 2gb but length < 2^14

fname = 'tmp006.h5';
h5create(fname,'/DS1',[536886272],'DataType','single');% does work
h5write(fname,'/DS1',1,1,1); % length > 2^14 but okay since filesize < 2gb
```

Error:

```
Warning: The following error was caught while executing 'H5ML.id' class destructor:
Error using hdf5lib2
The HDF5 library encountered an error and produced the following stack trace information:

    H5FD_truncate                   driver truncate request failed
    H5F_dest                        low level truncate failed
    H5F_try_close                   problems closing file
    H5O_close                       problem attempting file close
    H5D_close                       unable to release object header
    H5I_dec_app_ref                 can't decrement ID ref count
    H5I_dec_app_ref_always_close    can't decrement ID ref count
    H5Dclose                        can't decrement count on dataset ID

Error in H5ML.id/close (line 47)
                H5ML.hdf5lib2(obj.callback, obj.identifier);

Error in H5ML.id/delete (line 36)
        obj.close();
```

Comment: Just to check: Are you running a filesystem on the Linux side that has a max file size of 2 GB? (e.g. some 32-bitness in there?)